# adb for bootloop

Tags: adb, data-recovery, boot-loop, odin

I am in the middle of trying to understand the correct procedure to recover my data from a phone that went into a bootloop.

1. I installed android sdk, with adb tools.
2. Also installed ODIN (although I don't know how to use it for now)
3. Following commands I managed to perform and stuck on the last one, mounting sdcard

As I feel, that my phone data can be retrieved. Because I can still go into recovery mode, odin mode, can see the battery charging. Also able to detect the phone as MTP device in device manager although it doesn't show up under my computer as a portable device...

[image]

What are the steps should I follow to get rid of this bootloop and recover my data?
If adb command can mount my sdcard, doesn't it mean there's a way to recover the data?

In recovery mode I can see two options:
1. update from adb
2. update from external storage
I have already taken out my external sdcard, so I won't lose data in it along the built in sdcard. Here update from sdcard means built in card or external?
When I chose the 2nd option, I get the following error

```
 E: failed to mount /sdcard <No such file or directory>
```

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: You will find some useful hints in our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) and especially [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). In the latter, take a closer look at the "ADB Backups" section. Additionally, if your device is rooted, there's also the possibility to use `adb pull` to retrieve all contents from it.

Comment: @Izzy Praised to you! Could you please tell me which direction should I go first? I am now trying to do the command "adb sideload <update 4.2>" to update the phone via adb. But if I can pull all the contents from the phone then I don't have to do any updates because once data is pulled I could simply select wipe all...to reboot I guess..

Comment: All depends on whether you have root access on the device (without that, you cannot `adb pull` your stuff from `/data`). If you have no experience in that area, I'd recommend using one of the ADB Backup frontends to save your apps' data to separate archives (you could also try a full `adb backup`, then reset, and then restore all; if you're lucky that's all you need. But chances are you end up in the same situation then, so better be prepared). I guess you have your contacts/calendars synced with Google?

Comment: @Izzy I tried adb pull. It says remote object `data/data/...` doesn't exist. So does it mean the device is not rooted? What are the ADB backup frontends you are proposing? For me apps data not important - probably What'sApp. Most important are contacts, sms and picutre/pdf files. Nope unfortunately I always switch off Sync as Google was too intrusive.. :(

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss the leading `/`? `adb pull /data <target>`, see e.g. [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/adb-push-and-pull-Command.html). If the device is not rooted, you will get "permission denied" errors. If not using Google Sync (which I can perfectly understand), you should have taken care for backups of your contacts in advance! For recommendations: Please check the links to the tag-wikis I've posted. Information was placed there so we don't have to repeat it over and over again. Documents should be stored below `/sdcard`, which you can pull without root.

Comment: Yup I guess I didn't miss the leading `/` And thanks for the link which has so many adb sample commands. I feel my phone is at a very shallow soft bricked mode, which can be easily fixed...However as you said it all depends on if it's rooted or not. So looking at `adb shell` command I don't seem to get `#` instead `$`... When I typed `adb devices` within shell, it says device note found...so I am not really sure which direction I should be heading now.

Comment: I'm just a little confused: where did you type `adb devices`? If your device is not found, you neither could run `adb pull` against it. And right: `$` stands for non-root mode, `#` for root mode. You could try `su` to see if you can switch to root mode; `adb pull` however would require the ADB *server* on the device to run in root mode; [adbd Insecure](http://www.appbrain.com/app/%5Broot%5D-adbd-insecure/eu.chainfire.adbd) can be used to achieve that on a rooted device.

Comment: I roughly understood what you meant. So that's why I don't want to bring the phone back to Service centre or simply wipe data/factory set if there's a possibility to retrieve data...you can see from my images, what's shown for each command. I was not able to run `adb root`. After typing it nothing happened and cursor was just blinking in the command prompt

Comment: @Izzy I am yet to try out `su` commands. I realized wiping of cache didn't help until now. Going forward I would like to make a weekly automatic backup of my phone to the pc. Most people are talking about backup at recovery. Can I use clockworkmod software to backup my phone in the future? (given I have the full access and to root), is it really required to root the phone in order to use such softwares? I can read up, if you could provide me with some reliable links or wiki tags.

Comment: @Izzy I tried `adb shell`. However when typed `su`, I get the following `system/bin/sh: su: not found` So I managed to do `cd /system/` and I am successfully inside the system as well as `cd /sdcard/`. Now I am not sure what I could do...to retrieve the data...

Comment: Please, don't raise additional questions inside comments (in this case, you should ask your rooting/CWM questions in separate posts). This site does not work like a forum, it's a Q&A site (one question with its related answers per "page"). Your last comment confirms your device is *not* rooted, so there's no way to `adb pull` all your data from `/data`.

Comment: @Izzy I haven't tried this but can't @ aspiring install cwm using "install from SDCard" then try to root the rom? or after installing CWM make a backup of the Rom?

Comment: @RohanKandwal only saw your mssg after I did factory reset... NOw that my phone is back....I am trying to do the adb commands to root it... funny now I dont see anything...nothing detected. Also I want to mount it as a usb, so to try out recuva to retrieve any files....

Comment: @Izzy and everyone, I am quite glad, my contacts could be restored via (90%) What'sapp back up... THAT'S AMAZING!!! The backup includes all the messages, pictures I had with my contacts. However internal memory data, documents, pictures are still gone. And trying to recover.

Comment: Happy to know that you recovered some of your data. Hope you get everything back. xD

Comment: This is indeed one of those blessed times. After do the factory set and pc detected the phone, all pictures were FOUND. I mean how is that possible? But I am very glad that I didn't bring the phone back to Samsung service centre. I am thankful to all of you who supported help here. If it wasn't for you guys advices I would felt helpless and not had the opportunity to trying rooting from my end. At the end it paid off although I couldn't root. It is as bizzare as it looks... :-)

Answer (score -3):

I made a tool do help even the most the computer illiterate person recover their files using this method. You will, however need to follow the instructions in the article if you have not set up ADB.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=51822116